# Python int float rounding

Tags: python, casting, integer, rounding

While playing with python, I came across this:

```
a = 1/(2.2 - 2)

print a       #prints out 5.0
print int(a)  #prints out 4
```

I suspect the problem has something to do with binary number representation (expressing 1/5 in binary is tantamount to expressing 1/3 in decimal). Can someone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are quite right in your suspicion. The root cause is that 2.2 cannot be represented exactly as a `float`:

```
In [38]: '%.20f' % 2.2
Out[38]: '2.20000000000000017764'
```

The rest follows from this:

```
In [45]: '%.20f' % (2.2 - 2)
Out[45]: '0.20000000000000017764'

In [46]: '%.20f' % (1 / (2.2 - 2))
Out[46]: '4.99999999999999555911'
```